# Плавное уменьшение при скролле

Tags: javascript, css3

Задался вопросом: как осуществить данный эффект, который на промежутке 0:0 - 0:6?
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b2qlzo60aoc97zj/AAAzxfk11cf8IYgTGM8QGnM5a/videos?dl=0&preview=motion.mp4

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Обычно в шапку засовывают такой код, как вам понравился. Это анимация при скроле

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
     var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
    if (sc > 0) {
        $(".box").addClass("small")
    } else {
        $(".box").removeClass("small")
    }
});
```

```css
    .box {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:red;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.small {

width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
<div style='height:800px'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!